# How can I get an array from json?

Tags: c++, json

JSon data like this

```
{
    "timestamp": 1452658101628, 
    "resources": [
        {
            "uri": "/match/4236", 
            "resource": "/match/4236", 
            "body": {
                "matchid": 4236, 
                    },
    {....}
    ]
}
```

Code as Below:

```
string jsonString;
Json::Value value;
reader.parse(jsonString, value);
string matchId = value["resources"][0]["body"]["matchid"].asString();
```

When I make, I got below error:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator[]' in 'value.Json::Value::operator[](((const char*)"resources"))[0]'
../include/json/value.h:277: note: candidates are: Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::UInt)
../include/json/value.h:281: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](Json::Value::UInt) const
../include/json/value.h:294: note:                 Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](const char*)
../include/json/value.h:296: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](const char*) const
../include/json/value.h:298: note:                 Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](const std::string&)
../include/json/value.h:300: note:                 const Json::Value& Json::Value::operator[](const std::string&) const.
```

So can I resolve this and got my matchId?

Comment: i use [0U] resolved this issue, but i can't get my matchId all the same!!!

Comment: Your code is working on my PC, so I guess the problem is not with the code. I used `value["resources"][0]["body"]["matchid"].asString();` and it was fine.

Comment: what do you mean by "but i can't get my matchId all the same!!!"

Comment: Seems like the compiler is unable to determine 0 to be either Json::Value::UInt(0) or (const char *)0 (i.e. nullptr).

Comment: 0 is ambiguous because the conversion to `UInt` and `const char*` are both equal. 0U disambiguates that. I don't understand the second part of his sentence.

Comment: You might want to post in the question, what is the name of the json library you are using?

Comment: I'll bet a significant sum (several pennies) that they are using Jsoncpp.